# How to get MacBook Air 6.2 webcam to work in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: webcam, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu on my MacBook Air 6.2 and I am wondering if there is anyone that has got the new webcam in MacBook Air 6.2 to work? It seems like Apple has changed a lot since the last MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution yet.
Keep an eye on this  [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71131)